# SQL Server: using dm_exec_describe_first_result_set with table variable fires CREATE_TABLE trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I try to use sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set with query containing table variable to describe columns of the query.
But declare of table variable in this query is causing activation of DATABASE trigger for event AFTER CREATE_TABLE, which contains a calling of stored procedure with temp table.

Usual declare of table variable this trigger don't activate. Some ideas why is the trigger activated for table variable?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
BEGIN 
CREATE TABLE #A(b int)
INSERT INTO #A(b) VALUES(1)
DROP TABLE #A
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [CreateObjectDatabaseTrigger]
ON DATABASE 
AFTER 
    CREATE_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN
EXEC SP1
END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [CreateObjectDatabaseTrigger] ON DATABASE

DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DECLARE @A TABLE (b int) SELECT * FROM @A'

SELECT error_message, name 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
(@SqlQuery, NULL, 0)
```

Result with enabled trigger: The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #A(b) VALUES(1)' in procedure 'SP1' uses a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers should not return result sets to the client. Doing so is deprecated behavior and will be removed from a future version of SQL Server per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql).

In this case, use `PRINT` to return the informational message instead of a result set. The side-effect of this practice is that `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` will return the desired meta-data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [CreateObjectDatabaseTrigger]
ON DATABASE 
AFTER 
    CREATE_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN
PRINT 'Trigger activated';
END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [CreateObjectDatabaseTrigger] ON DATABASE;

DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DECLARE @A TABLE (b int) SELECT * FROM @A';

SELECT error_message, name 
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
(@SqlQuery, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SELECT statement in the trigger was there only for illustration. My real trigger contains calling of the stored procedure, which uses temp tables (CREATE TABLE #A), which are not supported in dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (The metadata could not be determined because statement 'SELECT * FROM #A' uses a temp table. Metadata discovery only supports temp tables when analyzing a single-statement batch.). So I want to avoid of the trigger activation.

Comment: @Martin, then you should edit your question to add code that demonstrates your actual problem.